# Find all ordered pairs of real numbers $(x, y)$ such that $x^2y^2 + 2xy^2 + 5x^2 + 3y^2 + 10x + 5 = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find all ordered pairs of real numbers $(x, y)$ such that $x^2y^2 + 2xy^2 + 5x^2 + 3y^2 + 10x + 5 = 0$?

I don't see a pattern, I don't know how to proceed.  Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$  y^2 \; ( x^2 + 2x + 3) = -5(x^2 + 2 x + 1) $$
$$  y^2 = -5 \; \; \frac{(x+1)^2 }{2 + (x+1)^2} $$
The right hand side is never positive. It is only zero when $x=-1$

Comment: Very clever. Nice noticing that $y$ appears only as $y^2$.

Answer (score 4):

$(y^2+5)x^2 + (2y^2+10)x +3y^2+5 = 0$

$\Delta = -8y^4 -40y^2 \leq 0$. The only solution is $y = 0$, which leads to $x = -1$.

Comment: Unless $y=0$. In that case $x=-1$.

Comment: I have edited. Thanks!